# How to determine the reason for high power draw on a laptop

Tags: command-line, power-management, battery, desktop-environments

I'm building some software that needs to run on a high-performance laptop, so that a person can carry it around in a backpack with an external camera feeding it real-time video via USB. When in the backpack, no-one will need to physically touch or look at the laptop - it is all monitored remotely.

When running the software while booted into desktop mode, `powertop` shows a power draw of about 10W

I thought I'd be clever and build a separate GRUB-initiated systemd target that skips the desktop and only requires `multi-user` mode (i.e. console mode only), and save power by turning off most of the unused CPUs. However my console mode draws a whopping 27W while idle.

This is was unexpected and baffling. I've tried comparing the output of `powertop` from both modes but can't make sense of what additional services or settings are run when the GUI is active that reduces the power draw on the laptop.

I've published the powertop output from both modes, in case someone can spot what I'm missing. (link: https://gist.github.com/xerxesb/883d6e2e60e6c7cf8be5e0cd643e5882)

However, I'm primarily looking for advice on how to diagnose why one boot mode draws more power than another.

Thanks

Comment: I would try without disabling CPUs, as idle CPU don't use much power anyhow. I would also try an independent method from powertop, such as turbostat.

Comment: I tried online verses offline CPUs on my test computer and there was no power draw difference. I put your two powertop listings side by side and could not find any explanation. Perhaps something else is not getting setup correctly resulting in wasted power. You could just let it go for long enough to determine if the reported power draw is real or not. i.e. does the battery really drain 3X faster?

Comment: @DougSmythies Thanks for the tips - I'll look into `turbostat` and re-check my CPU idling assumptions :). I can confirm that the power draw is indeed that fast. The unit drained to flat within 2 hours without any additional software running

Comment: O.K suggest this command (that i pretty much always have running): `sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt --interval 6`. Note I am a server person and don't know about graphics and such, you might want to add `GFXWatt` to your turbostat command. ...but I suspect the issue is elsewhere, not sure...

Answer (score 0):

In the end I ran out of time to try and get to the bottom of what the actual differences are between booting into `graphical.target` vs booting into `multi-user.target`.

I changed my service to depend on `graphical.target` and accepted the fact that GDM is just idling there in the background, but it's hard to argue with the substantially lower power draw.

I run this `echo 0 | sudo tee $(find /sys/devices -path '*backlight/brightness')` at the end of the script to turn off the screen backlight and it just works.

I know this isn't a really satisfying answer, but it's the solution we went with.